# Large amounts of traffic on an idle cifs mount

Tags: arch-linux, cifs

If I leave a cifs mount idle for an extended period (time frame not consistent, 20 minutes, an hour) I ineveitably end up with a massive amount of traffic that begins to generate between the Windows 2008 R2 share and my Arch Linux box. This is a releatively new occurance (3 months, maybe longer). Mount.cifs and Kernel versions:

```
mount.cifs -V: 6.7
uname -r: 4.10.11-1-ARCH
```

The share is mounted with the following:

```
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.1.1/FileShares/rod /home/rod/mnt/FileShares/rod -o credentials=/path/to/.credentials.txt,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g),iocharset=utf8
```

I perform a wire capture with tcpdump:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -s0 -w /tmp/cifs-traffic.pcap host 192.168.1.1 and port 445
```

...and get lots of the following:

```
11:18:28.150447 IP 192.168.0.100.49784 > 192.168.1.1.445: tcp 0
  0x0000:  4500 0034 5d30 4000 4006 c78a 0a01 000a  E..4]0@.@.......
  0x0010:  0a01 01fe c278 01bd d50a 85a5 ce74 6350  .....x.......tcP
  0x0020:  8010 00e5 3641 0000 0101 080a 551b cb1f  ....6A......U...
  0x0030:  012f b778                                ./.x
11:18:28.150491 IP 192.168.0.100.49784 > 192.168.1.1.445: tcp 42
  0x0000:  4500 005e 5d31 4000 4006 c75f 0a01 000a  E..^]1@.@.._....
  0x0010:  0a01 01fe c278 01bd d50a 85a5 ce74 6350  .....x.......tcP
  0x0020:  8018 00e5 99dc 0000 0101 080a 551b cb1f  ............U...
  0x0030:  012f b778 0000 0026 ff53 4d42 2b00 0000  ./.x...&.SMB+...
  0x0040:  0000 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
  0x0050:  ffff 2213 0000 0000 0101 0001 0061       .."..........a
```

Anyone have any ideas as to what this is or what to look at next?

Comment: Did you ever solve what this was? I've got a similar issue on a Linux Mint computer

Comment: I never did find an answer, but about 2 weeks ago I noticed that it seemed to have stopped. I am assuming it was a package or kernel update that resolved it. Good luck on your issue.

Comment: I found the same after a kernel update, so I guess it was a bug in the kernel that was fixed.